# Can you deploy bicep template with AzureResourceGroupDeployment task?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

Can you deploy directly bicep templates within a devops pipeline as in the following task?
I keep getting issues about not being able to find the file so I'm wondering whether this task is just for json artifact deployment and not .bicep files

```
  - task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@3
    displayName: "X) AzureResourceGroupDeployment"
    enabled: true
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureServiceConnection}}
      action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group' # Options: create Or Update Resource Group, select Resource Group, start, stop, stopWithDeallocate, restart, delete, deleteRG
      resourceGroupName: "$(resourceGroupNameVar)"
      location: "${{parameters.location}}" # Required when action == Create Or Update Resource Group
      templateLocation: 'Linked artifact' # Options: linked Artifact, uRL Of The File
      csmFile: bicep/modules/storageAccount.bicep # Required when  TemplateLocation == Linked Artifact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With version 3 of the task, no. You have to transpile the Bicep to JSON first.
i.e.

```
- script: | 
    az bicep install 
    az bicep build -f $BICEP_FILE_PATH
  displayName: 'Build Bicep'
  env:
    BICEP_FILE_PATH: ${{ parameters.BicepPath }}/${{ parameters.BicepTemplateName}}.bicep
```

Alternately, you could skip using the task and just use the `az deployment` command.

Comment: Thank you, I'll raise an issue with microsoft as the documentation is a bit misleading https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3

Comment: @user15464793 Yeah, I think it only supports it for templates from a storage account, which seems like a weird distinction but matches with my experience.